# How do you convert a library function with two completion handlers into an async function?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, wrapper, completionhandler

I need to wrap a function as below from a library into an async function. The error on my First Trial as below is:

> Missing argument for parameter 'errorHandler' in call.

How can I wrap it properly? Your comments will be appreciated.

**Original Function**:

```swift
func createConverter(id: String, successHandler: @escaping (Converter) -> Void, errorHandler: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Cancellable
```

```swift
func createConverter(id: String) async throws -> Converter {
    return await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({
        (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Converter, Error>) in
        createConverter(id: id) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let converter):
                continuation.resume(returning: converter)
            case .failure(let error):
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `createConverter` Takes 2 separate closures, but you’re only calling it with 1. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/ for a really good walkthrough

Comment: just throw the error instead or return a Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original `createConverter` has three parameters, you need to provide all three. You are missing the 3rd. Your attempt assumes there is only one closure parameter (of type `Result<Converter, Error>`) instead of the two separate closure parameters.

You should also add `try` before the `await`.

```
func createConverter(id: String) async throws -> Converter {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Converter, Error>) in
        let cancellable = createConverter(id: id) { (converter: Converter) in
            continuation.resume(returning: converter)
        } errorHandler: { error in
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles but I have no way to verify the result. This also makes no use of the original `Cancellable` return value of the original `createConverter`.

Since I don't have whatever library you have, this was verified in a Playground using the following:

```
import Combine

// Dummy
struct Converter {
}

// Original function
func createConverter(id: String, successHandler: @escaping (Converter) -> Void, errorHandler: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Cancellable {
    return AnyCancellable { // Just enough so it compiles
    }
}

// New function
func createConverter(id: String) async throws -> Converter {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Converter, Error>) in
        let cancellable = createConverter(id: id) { (converter: Converter) in
            continuation.resume(returning: converter)
        } errorHandler: { error in
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much HagarRash. Your correction compiles with a little modification of

Comment: Looks like you hit return to soon. What needs to be changed? The code I posted compiled fine for me.

Comment: (throwing error as! Error) for the error type conforming a protocol in the library. Actually I was not accustomed with putting second closure parameter.

Comment: Let Xcode do code completion for you. It makes it so much simpler than trying to get the syntax correct by hand.

Comment: By highlighting the function name(Class.function) and right-clicking, I could not see the 'Wrap to async' option activated.